# Django - How to construct a subquery to go two foreign keys deep?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I've been learning Django recently but I have a complicated situation and I'm not sure what the right subquery should be.

Users can post Comments on Posts which belong to Topics. For a particular user, I want to find the Topic they most commented in. Ties can be broken arbitrarily.

Here are the relevant portions of the models:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Post(models.Model):
    topic - models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

User model is the default django.contrib model

I'm not sure how to do this in one query? I think I should be able to annotate all Topics based on number of Comments that I filter on user id, and then iterate over those topics to get the max, but that seems inefficent, and I'm not even sure how to write that in Django query form

Answer (score 0):

Annotate comments by topic count.

something like:

```
user.comments_set.values('post__topic')\
        .annotate(count=Count('post__topic'))\
        .order_by('-count')
```

where `user`  is your specific user. it will return a queryset with topic id and count, like:

```
<QuerySet [{'post__topic': 2, 'count': 4}, {'post__topic': 1, 'count': 2}, {'post__topic': 3, 'count': 1}]>
```

*be sure you imported `Count` from `django.db.models`